# Latex cannot find sty files

Tags: texlive

I put `Rd.sty` in `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\Rd.sty`. But when I try to execute a file, say `aaa.tex` then the error  `! LaTeX Error: File  "Rd.sty"  not found.`  occur. But, if I put the `Rd.sty` and `aaa.tex`  in the same directory, then it goes well.  Why??

---

**Answer** *of my questions by Ulrike Fisher*, I reprint here.

1. Put the `.sty` file, e.g., `Rd.sty` at `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\Rd.sty`
2. Execute the code `mktexlsr` from the command prompt to reflect the change as follows:

   C:\Users\User>mktexlsr

Then, we no longer need to put the `Rd.sty` and some `tex` file in the same directory.

---

We confirm whether LaTeX can detect the `.sty` file or not via the code `kpsewhich style_file_name` in the command prompt,

```
C:\Users\User>  kpsewhich Rd.sty
            <--- Here nothing since LaTeX cannot detect the Rd.sty
C:\Users\User>mktexlsr      <--- Up date
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2013/texmf-config/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2013/texmf-config/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2013/texmf-var/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2013/texmf-var/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Done.

>  kpsewhich Rd.sty
c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/Rd.sty <--- Here LaTeX can detect the Rd.sty
```

Comment: Thank you, I use Windows 10, but I try it.

Comment: 'Rd.sty' file is user defined style files. you can ask you client. or who used it.

Comment: `Rd.sty` is required  when I make a manual for my statistical package. This package can find at `https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/share/texmf/tex/latex/Rd.sty` So, I copy and paste with extension `.sty`. I am not sure but  R users are familiar with `Rd.sty` ?

Comment: On texlive you need to run mktexlsr to update the fndb.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer !! I can do !! You are greate !! I appreciate you very much. I bothered this issues for very long time !! I reprint you answer as above.

Comment: Thank you @JouleV  for editon !! But I find a miss in my sentence so I overwrite from your editon !! But I appreciate you !!

Comment: @CamfordOxbridge You are welcome!